# Renderer2.appendChild is not working as expected?

Tags: angular

in Angular component, I am trying to create a new `input` html element and insert in specific location of the template

the component code

```js
@ViewChild('pickerLocation', { static: false }) pLocationSpan: ElementRef<HTMLSpanElement>;

constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    const pickerInput = this.renderer.createElement('INPUT');
    const picker = new TempusDominus(pickerInput);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.pLocationSpan.nativeElement, pickerInput);
  }
```

the template code

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="datetimepickerInput">{{label}}</label>
    <span id="locationSpan" ngModel #pickerLocation></span>
    <span class="input-group-text">
        <span class="fa-solid fa-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

however if I changed the line

`this.renderer.appendChild(this.pLocationSpan.nativeElement, pickerInput);`

to

`this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, pickerInput);`

it works, however I need the input in specific location. so what could be the problem??

Comment: Have you tried to use 'static:true'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ViewChild` query for elements is only possible in `NgAfterViewInit()` lifecycle the earliest. Because `<span #pickerLocation>` needs to be rendered first before it can be queried and accessed.

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const pickerInput = this.renderer.createElement('INPUT');
    const picker = new TempusDominus(pickerInput);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.pLocationSpan.nativeElement, pickerInput);
  }
```